# Proof about limit of a monotone increasing sequence bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(b_n)$ be a monotone increasing sequence bounded above by $K$. Can you show that it converges to a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(b_n)$ doesn't converge to a limit, it must keep growing, and hence is not bounded above by $K$.

Comment: This is not an answer anyway. The proof is based on completeness of real number and is not trivial at all as your answer indicates.

Comment: As @ParamanandSingh said your sequence could converge and be bounded but might not exist at all! It would do good in very elementary classes of sequences.

Answer (score 3):

$(bn)$ is bounded above $\implies \exists sup(b_n)$

So $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \implies \exists b_N \in (b_n) : sup(b_n)-b_N \lt \epsilon$

So $\forall n\ge N$ we have $sup(b_n)-b_n \le sup(b_n)-b_N \lt \epsilon$

Therefore, $\exists lim_n {b_n} = sup(b_n)$.